# SetWindowPlacement won't correct placement for WPF tool windows

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I'm p-invoking into [SetWindowPlacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in my WPF app to save and restore the window location. This works great but the advertised capacity to make sure a window is never completely hidden doesn't seem to function when the window is a tool window rather than a standard window. You call SetWindowPlacement with negative Left and Right placements and it will happily open it off-screen with no way of getting it back on.

Is there a way I can make SetWindowPlacement correct the placement for these tool windows (for missing monitors and such)?

Failing that, is there a good manual way to do it? For reference, the code:

```
// RECT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;

    public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        this.Left = left;
        this.Top = top;
        this.Right = right;
        this.Bottom = bottom;
    }
}

// POINT structure required by WINDOWPLACEMENT structure
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINT
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;

    public POINT(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
}

// WINDOWPLACEMENT stores the position, size, and state of a window
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
{
    public int length;
    public int flags;
    public int showCmd;
    public POINT minPosition;
    public POINT maxPosition;
    public RECT normalPosition;
}

public static class WindowPlacement
{
    private static Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    private static XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, [In] ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, out WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

    private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
    private const int SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2;

    public static void SetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle, string placementXml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(placementXml))
        {
            return;
        }

        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement;
        byte[] xmlBytes = encoding.GetBytes(placementXml);

        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(xmlBytes))
            {
                placement = (WINDOWPLACEMENT)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }

            placement.length = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT));
            placement.flags = 0;
            placement.showCmd = (placement.showCmd == SW_SHOWMINIMIZED ? SW_SHOWNORMAL : placement.showCmd);

            SetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, ref placement);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // Parsing placement XML failed. Fail silently.
        }
    }

    public static string GetPlacement(IntPtr windowHandle)
    {
        WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
        GetWindowPlacement(windowHandle, out placement);

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, placement);
                byte[] xmlBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                return encoding.GetString(xmlBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling SetPlacement with Top: 200, Bottom: 600, Left: -1000, Right: -300.

Comment: There are pretty explicit warnings in the MSDN article for WINDOWPLACEMENT about the difference between workspace and screen coordinates and how tool windows are different.  Nothing to look at so I can only assume you are getting it wrong somehow.  Don't keep your code a secret.

Comment: The difference between workspace and screen coordinates isn't the issue here. I've attached the code but the heart of the issue is calling SetPlacement on a tool window with a normal placement RECT that's outside the normal screen area.

Comment: Actually you don't need explicit XML serialization: you can store an instance of WINDOWPLACEMENT in settings as is. By the way, WIndows 7 as of now seems to adjust the position if it's outside the visible area for now. Otherwise, thank you for sharing your code!

Comment: @Vlad The settings UI has weird behavior when you try to just save it as-is. Also in my case I don't save it with the built-in settings; I am storing in a sqlite database. Also when you saw it adjust the position of the window outside the viewable area, were you using a regular window or a tool window?

Comment: @RandomEngy: I didn't notice any weird behavior with VS 2019's settings. The database is of course a different story.

Comment: @RandomEngy: You are right, I see the automatic adjustment for the regular windows, not tool windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your proposed window rectangle to `MonitorFromRect()` with the `MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST` flag. This will return an `HMONITOR` representing the monitor the window most intersects (is on) - or if the window is completely off-screen, the nearest monitor to the proposed coords.

You can then call `GetMonitorInfo()` to find the monitor's display and workspace rectangles, and bounds-check your proposed window coords to make sure the window is completely on-screen before you show it.

Answer (score 6):

From Jonathan's answer I came up with this code to rescue the window manually:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MONITORINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public RECT rcMonitor;
    public RECT rcWork;
    public uint dwFlags;
}
```

...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromRect([In] ref RECT lprc, uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, ref MONITORINFO lpmi);


private const uint MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;
```

...

```
IntPtr closestMonitorPtr = MonitorFromRect(ref placement.normalPosition, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
MONITORINFO closestMonitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
closestMonitorInfo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (MONITORINFO));
bool getInfoSucceeded = GetMonitorInfo(closestMonitorPtr, ref closestMonitorInfo);

if (getInfoSucceeded && !RectanglesIntersect(placement.normalPosition, closestMonitorInfo.rcMonitor))
{
    placement.normalPosition = PlaceOnScreen(closestMonitorInfo.rcMonitor, placement.normalPosition);
}
```

...

```
private static bool RectanglesIntersect(RECT a, RECT b)
{
    if (a.Left > b.Right || a.Right < b.Left)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (a.Top > b.Bottom || a.Bottom < b.Top)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static RECT PlaceOnScreen(RECT monitorRect, RECT windowRect)
{
    int monitorWidth = monitorRect.Right - monitorRect.Left;
    int monitorHeight = monitorRect.Bottom - monitorRect.Top;

    if (windowRect.Right < monitorRect.Left)
    {
        // Off left side
        int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
        if (width > monitorWidth)
        {
            width = monitorWidth;
        }

        windowRect.Left = monitorRect.Left;
        windowRect.Right = windowRect.Left + width;
    }
    else if (windowRect.Left > monitorRect.Right)
    {
        // Off right side
        int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
        if (width > monitorWidth)
        {
            width = monitorWidth;
        }

        windowRect.Right = monitorRect.Right;
        windowRect.Left = windowRect.Right - width;
    }

    if (windowRect.Bottom < monitorRect.Top)
    {
        // Off top
        int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;
        if (height > monitorHeight)
        {
            height = monitorHeight;
        }

        windowRect.Top = monitorRect.Top;
        windowRect.Bottom = windowRect.Top + height;
    }
    else if (windowRect.Top > monitorRect.Bottom)
    {
        // Off bottom
        int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;
        if (height > monitorHeight)
        {
            height = monitorHeight;
        }

        windowRect.Bottom = monitorRect.Bottom;
        windowRect.Top = windowRect.Bottom - height;
    }

    return windowRect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution (based on RandomEngy's code) that extends the Window class with a KeepInsideNearestMonitor() method that ensure WPF Window placement within the currently visible bounds. It comes without Win32 and works with regard to the calling factor that you can setup in Windows 10 via Right Click on Desktop>Display Settings.

```
public static class WindowExtension
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;

        public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            this.Left = left;
            this.Top = top;
            this.Right = right;
            this.Bottom = bottom;
        }
    }

    internal static void KeepInsideNearestMonitor(this Window floatingWindow)
    {
        RECT normalPosition = new RECT();
        normalPosition.Left = (int)floatingWindow.FloatingLeft;
        normalPosition.Top = (int)floatingWindow.FloatingTop;
        normalPosition.Bottom = normalPosition.Top + (int)floatingWindow.FloatingHeight;
        normalPosition.Right = normalPosition.Left + (int)floatingWindow.FloatingWidth;

        // Are we using only one monitor?
        if (SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth == SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth &&
            SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight == SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight)
        {
            RECT primaryscreen = new RECT(0,0, (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth, (int)SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight);

            if (!RectanglesIntersect(normalPosition, primaryscreen))
            {
                normalPosition = PlaceOnScreen(primaryscreen, normalPosition);

                floatingWindow.FloatingLeft = normalPosition.Left;
                floatingWindow.FloatingTop = normalPosition.Top;
                floatingWindow.FloatingHeight = normalPosition.Bottom - normalPosition.Top;
                floatingWindow.FloatingWidth = normalPosition.Right - normalPosition.Left;
            }

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            RECT primaryscreen = new RECT(0, 0, (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth, (int)SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight);

            if (!RectanglesIntersect(normalPosition, primaryscreen))
            {
                normalPosition = PlaceOnScreen(primaryscreen, normalPosition);

                floatingWindow.FloatingLeft = normalPosition.Left;
                floatingWindow.FloatingTop = normalPosition.Top;
                floatingWindow.FloatingHeight = normalPosition.Bottom - normalPosition.Top;
                floatingWindow.FloatingWidth = normalPosition.Right - normalPosition.Left;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether <paramref name="a"/> and <paramref name="b"/>
    /// have an intersection or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool RectanglesIntersect(RECT a, RECT b)
    {
        if (a.Left > b.Right || a.Right < b.Left)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (a.Top > b.Bottom || a.Bottom < b.Top)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine the place where <paramref name="windowRect"/> should be placed
    /// inside the <paramref name="monitorRect"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="monitorRect"></param>
    /// <param name="windowRect"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static RECT PlaceOnScreen(RECT monitorRect, RECT windowRect)
    {
        int monitorWidth = monitorRect.Right - monitorRect.Left;
        int monitorHeight = monitorRect.Bottom - monitorRect.Top;

        if (windowRect.Right < monitorRect.Left)
        {
            // Off left side
            int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
            if (width > monitorWidth)
            {
                width = monitorWidth;
            }

            windowRect.Left = monitorRect.Left;
            windowRect.Right = windowRect.Left + width;
        }
        else if (windowRect.Left > monitorRect.Right)
        {
            // Off right side
            int width = windowRect.Right - windowRect.Left;
            if (width > monitorWidth)
            {
                width = monitorWidth;
            }

            windowRect.Right = monitorRect.Right;
            windowRect.Left = windowRect.Right - width;
        }

        if (windowRect.Bottom < monitorRect.Top)
        {
            // Off top
            int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;
            if (height > monitorHeight)
            {
                height = monitorHeight;
            }

            windowRect.Top = monitorRect.Top;
            windowRect.Bottom = windowRect.Top + height;
        }
        else if (windowRect.Top > monitorRect.Bottom)
        {
            // Off bottom
            int height = windowRect.Bottom - windowRect.Top;
            if (height > monitorHeight)
            {
                height = monitorHeight;
            }

            windowRect.Bottom = monitorRect.Bottom;
            windowRect.Top = windowRect.Bottom - height;
        }

        return windowRect;
    }
}
```